# Unity App for mobile

Tags: unity

I'm a newbie here
I'm willing to acquire a unity game from a developper and he mentionned that the app is Optimized for Mobile Devices.
Does it mean I can build it for android and export the apk file?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Unity can export for Both IOS and Android...
so yes.